# I can't convert Json to string [OctoberCms]

Tags: php, json, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to get the value from an input, that input allows the user to create as many fields as he wants this is how I have created that field in my fields.yaml:

```
str_og_fb_admins:
        label: Facebook admins
        comment: Insert here the admins names
        span: left
        tab: Facebook
        type: repeater
        form:
          fields:
            str_og_fb_admins:
              label: Facebook admins
              type: text
```

then on my component I'm calling it this way:

```
$settings = Settings::instance();
$this->ogFbAdmins = $settings->str_og_fb_admins;
```

but now I want to get the single values from each singular input and I don't know how, I have tried to use the `json_decode();` function but it returns an error.

If I use `echo json_encode($this->ogFbAdmins);` it returns

```
{"1":{"str_og_fb_admins":"admin1"},"2":{"str_og_fb_admins":"admin2"}}
```

but I want to make it return like this:

```
admin1
admin2
```

How do I make it to return in the second way?

ps: the error that returns when I use `json_decode($this->ogFbadmins);` is like this:

"json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `$this->ogFbAdmins` is an array so you dont need any JSON conversion at all.

Try treating it like an array in Pure PHP

```
$settings = Settings::instance();
$this->ogFbAdmins = $settings->str_og_fb_admins;
foreach ($this->ogFbAdmins as $adm) {
    echo $adm['str_og_fb_admins'];
}
```

Now the inner structure may be an object so you may need to do

```
$settings = Settings::instance();
$this->ogFbAdmins = $settings->str_og_fb_admins;
foreach ($this->ogFbAdmins as $adm) {
    echo $adm->str_og_fb_admins;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

**PHP**

```
$ogFbAdmins = json_decode(json_encode($this->ogFbAdmins), true);
foreach($ogFbAdmins as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['str_og_fb_admins'] . "\n";
}
```

[EVAL.IN](https://eval.in/581508)

Comment: Why do you feel the need to convert a PHP data structure into a JSON String just to convert it back to a PHP data structure, to address it using normal PHP. **None of that is necessary**!